# How do I change the product key for Windows Server 2003 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2003, activation, licensing

I have installed Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition (x86) onto a machine and activated it using the wrong product key.  Is there a procedure to reenter and reactivate Windows with the correct key that does not involve reinstalling the OS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Magical Jelly Bean Key Finder

[Download Site](http://magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/)

Comment: That shows the key but I can't find an option to change it or to reset activation.

Comment: Sorry about that, the updated version removed that functionality. Try this version: http://www.magicaljellybean.com/files/keyfinder.v1.51.zip Make sure you backup your activation files first.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article, its for XP, but should work all the same. You need to basically deactivate your copy, then instead of re-activating, change the key. Make sure its the same type of install media that the new key comes from. (Retail, OEM, VL)

http://www.petrikb.com/change_the_serial_in_windows_xp.htm